# "Орава" от слова "орать"?

Tags: этимология

Большую толпу людей еще называют "орава". Интересно, это потому, что они все орут, или тут другой корень?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Орава- от глагола орать (пахать). "Совместная работа в поле" - по одной из версий. Потом значение немного переменилось. Всей оравой - всей гурьбой, всей толпой. 
Были оравы, остались облавы и забавы, старинные русские развлечения от скуки...